# Position:fixed destroys the grid in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I want to achieve a pretty simple layout with a fixed-top navbar (full page width), and below that two columns (one col-2, the other col-10) that fill the remaining height. The first column is set to `postion: fixed` because only the second should be scrollable.

While I was able to accomplish this, the moment I wrap the columns in a container, the fixed column on the left gets a bigger width than it should:

```
<div class="container" style="width:50%;">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 bg-primary" style="position:fixed;">
        Test
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-2 bg-primary">
        Test
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a very simple snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/q0ew8agb/) that shows this behavior when one column has a fixed position.

Why is it doing that? Is there a way around?

Comment: Have you tried using `position: sticky;`? This way you can scroll to your content and the fixed or sticky column will remain in the same spot

Comment: That seems to work indeed, thanks for the suggestion! Still puzzled about how `position: fixed` behaves in this particular case though... would you mind clarifying that a bit so I can learn from it?

Comment: I have no idea, in all honesty, I just got so frustrated trying to make it work that I gave up. I found sticky worked and now use it in all of my projects. Even bootstrap kind of says you may have to mess with the css to get fixed to work for a specific use case: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/utilities/position/#sticky-top

Comment: @Paulie_D good point. Fixed that. Not sure about the downvotes though... can't see why this shouldn't be a valid question.

Comment: `position:fixed` is related to the **viewport** not any grid. I suggest you re-think

Comment: @binoculars Setting `position: fixed` takes the element out of the document flow, so it doesn't actually interact with the other elements in terms of the height, width, or other styling properties that you set, grid-layout in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

As per your my understanding, you want a fixed navbar and want to set two columns below the navbar. In that column one  should be sticky and 2nd one should be scrollable. Below is the working snippet for the same

```css
.sticky-top {
  z-index: 9999;
  height:100%;
}

.main {
  top: 56px!important; /*set it according to height of nav bar*/
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class='container-fluid'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-2 align-self-start sticky-top main'>
       sidebar1
      </div>
      <div class='col-10 main'>
        This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until
        the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main
        will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar will stick to the top. This main will continue scrolling until the bottom while the sidebar
        will stick to the top.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If user is facing sticky issue in IE and old browsers, this JS could be useful instead 'position: sticky' CSS.

```js
(function($) {
 $.fn.sticky = function( options ) {
  var settings = $.extend({
   stickyTop : 0,
   stickyBottom : 0,
   widthLimit: 0,
   stickyClass: false,
   stickyParent: false
  }, options);
  return this.each( function() {
   var $ele = $(this);
   var eleTop, eleLeft, eleBottom, eleParBot, eleWid, winWid
   var r = function(){
    eleTop = $ele.offset().top - settings.stickyTop;
    eleLeft = $ele.offset().left;
    eleBottom = $ele.offset().top + $ele.innerHeight() + settings.stickyBottom;
    $eleParent = $ele.parents(settings.stickyParent) || $ele.parent();
    eleParBot = $eleParent.offset().top + $eleParent.innerHeight();
    eleWid = $ele.innerWidth();
    winWid = $(window).outerWidth();
    f();
   }
   var f = function(){
    var winTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(winTop >= eleTop && winWid > settings.widthLimit){
     $ele.css({
      'position': 'fixed',
      'top': settings.stickyTop,
      'left': eleLeft,
      'width': eleWid
     });
     if (settings.stickyClass != false) {
      $ele.addClass(settings.stickyClass);
     }
     if(winTop >= eleParBot-$ele.innerHeight()-settings.stickyTop+settings.stickyBottom){
      $ele.css('top', (winTop - eleParBot + $ele.innerHeight() - settings.stickyBottom) * -1);
     }
     else{
      $ele.css('top', settings.stickyTop);
     }  
    }
    else{
     $ele.removeAttr('style').removeClass(settings.stickyClass);
    }
   }
   r();
   $(window).scroll(f);
   $(window).resize(function(){
    $ele.removeAttr('style');
    r();
   });
  });
 }

}(jQuery));
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.header-logo').sticky({
  stickyParent: 'body',
  stickyTop: 0,
  stickyBottom: 0,
  stickyClass: 'sticky',
  widthLimit: 575
 });
});
```

```css
*, *:after, *:before{
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
 font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
 background-color: #fff;
 padding: 0px;    
 height: 1500px;
}
.header-nav{
 background-color: #ddd;
}
.header-logo{
 background-color: #ccc;
}
.header-logo a{
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 30px;
 padding: 20px 0;
 color: #1d1d1d;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.header-logo.sticky{
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
}
.header-logo.sticky a{
 color: #fff;
}
.header-navbar{
 padding-top: 18px;
 padding-bottom: 18px;
}
.header-navbar ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style-type: none;
}
.header-navbar li{
 padding: 5px 20px;
}
.header-navbar li:last-child{
 padding-right: 0;
}
.header-navbar li a{
 color: #1d1d1d;
 text-decoration: none;
}
.more-pen{
 position: fixed;
 right: 20px;
 bottom: 20px;
 text-align: right;
 text-transform: capitalize;
}
.more-pen a{
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 5px 20px;
 background-color: #1d1d1d;
 color: #fff;
 border-radius: 4px;
 text-decoration: none;
 transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.more-pen a:hover{
 background-color: #8647db;
}
.more-pen a .fa{
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container header-nav">
 <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-end">
  <div class="col-sm-2 header-logo"><a href="#">Logo</a></div>
  <div class="col-sm-10 header-navbar">
   <ul class="d-flex ml-auto justify-content-sm-end">
    <li>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="more-pen">
 <a href="https://codepen.io/AsfanShaikh/pen/PrPgZb" target="_blank">For more Stickybar JS demo <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: consider explaining why this answer is helpful and how it solves the OP's problem

Comment: If user is facing sticky issue in IE and old browsers, this JS could be useful instead 'position: sticky' CSS. You can check CodePen demo here: [https://codepen.io/AsfanShaikh/pen/LKNdye]

Comment: You should add that explanation to your answer, not in a comment. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: OK thanks. I am new here. I'll keep this in mind. So, should I delete this answer?

Comment: Welcome! No you can just edit your answer and add an explanation. It’s always good to explain your answer, especially when the provided code is long. We try to write well-researched questions and answers here. Also please don’t post your answer more than once.